# Extra default padding problem CSS for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have that CSS for one of my elements:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3B3B3B 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
```

When I inspect it at Firebug it is like:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #3B3B3B 0%, #FFFFFF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

When I look  at my page it has some paddings from top left down and bottom. How can I solve it?

**PS:**
The problem is that. I give that style into a a div as like:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div id ="myDiv">
....//That div is just under the body element so includes everything.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

At firefox `html` element is upper than that div element and if I give that style into html element I can not see the result at my div.

It works at Chrome, I get this error at Firefox.

Comment: provide the link of your page, or create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It is not easy to see that effect at jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you removed the `margin` and `padding` from your `html`, `body`, `div` elements?

Something like:

```
html, body{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}

#myDiv{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3B3B3B 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
   //OTHER STYLES 
}
```

Comment: margin-o to my body element soleves the problem